# Error trying to make rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.20_16317.20160108

Tags: drivers, make

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals). Paste the text directly to your question and apply code formatting (the `{}` icon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminal, navigate to the driver file:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.20_16317.20160108
```

Next, edit the Makefile:

```
nano Makefile
```

Find the line that reads like this:

```
#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=date-time   # Fix compile error on gcc 4.9 and later
```

Change it to read like this:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=date-time    # Fix compile error on gcc 4.9 and later
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Now recompile:

```
make clean
make
```

Assuming there are no further errors:

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: Don't forget, when you get an updated kernel, recompile: make clean, make, sudo make install. Glad it's working!